# Django - Allowing super user to review all interactions to the database and generate reports

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am designing an application where any member of staff can add items into the database (using SQLite3) and was wondering if there was a way to get it so that the admin (superuser) can review all these changes and additions to the database before they are displayed? The idea being if I'm logged in as the superuser and go to the admin side a panel will display everything that the staff have done and allow for additions and edits to be accepted or rejected.

I am also unsure if there is a way to generate reports for the application, one that would show new additions to the database and maybe allow the super user to download a csv or something. I'm using Django 1.7 and python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

[`django-reversion`](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) is an app that allows for a few of the things you are looking for:

- Roll back to any point in a model instance's history.
- Recover deleted model instances.
- Simple admin integration.

Setup is easy; add to `INSTALLED_APPS` and migrate, then subclass the `VersionAdmin` class provided. The app itself creates db tables of all actions performed, who performed them, when, and serialized representations of the model that can be restored. Setup is that easy, no need to override models or go hog wild.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin

@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    pass
```

You will have to create your own `AdminAction` for reports, but can use the bundled [VersionQuerySet](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#reversion-models-versionqueryset) class to retrieve all revisions for a given model. This is easy enough, especially when using [Django AdminActions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

```
for revision in Version.objects.get_for_model(model, model_db=None):
    output_contents += '|'.join([str(revision.model), revision.user])
    output_contents += '\r\n'
```

---

Somewhat related is [`django-moderation`](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-gatekeeper), where you register a model w/ a hook and then can require moderation for model objects. Take a look at the additional Manager methods you get when using this:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all().approved()     # approved by moderator
>>> MyModel.objects.all().pending()      # pending in moderation queue
>>> MyModel.objects.all().rejected()     # rejected by moderator
>>> MyModel.objects.all().flagged()      # flagged
>>> MyModel.objects.all().not_flagged()  # not flagged
```

Objects changed by a non-moderator are placed in a queue and approved/rejected via the admin.

These two can work together and should cover your needs when used in tandem.